# fetching specific data from JSON with python

Tags: python, json, django, api

I want to fetch specific data form JSON . Right now I can fetch all of the data and convert it into JSON format. But I only want to fetch "home_team" and "away_team" of all the sets.

My code to fetch all of the data is:`

```
import json
import requests

reap = requests.get('https://app.sportdataapi.com/api/v1/soccer/matches?apikey=64572f90-88d6-11eb-8a43-7106c933e99d&season_id=496&date_from=2020-09-19&fbclid=IwAR2zkLfVHG1xyxCrKQdcvCqhYhyjp5vA2TtbAsXZ3R3pVFJKV3jnhgFdjG4')
data = reap.json()
print(data)
```

And my JSON data is:

```
{'query': {'apikey': '64572f90-88d6-11eb-8a43-7106c933e99d', 'season_id': '496', 'date_from': '2020-09-19', 'fbclid': 'IwAR2zkLfVHG1xyxCrKQdcvCqhYhyjp5vA2TtbAsXZ3R3pVFJKV3jnhgFdjG4'}, 'data': [{'match_id': 139415, 'status_code': 3, 'status': 'finished', 'match_start': '2020-09-19 13:30:00', 'match_start_iso': '2020-09-19T13:30:00+00:00', 'minute': None, 'league_id': 314, 'season_id': 496, 'stage': {'stage_id': 1, 'name': 'Regular Season'}, 'group': {'group_id': 222, 'group_name': 'Bundesliga'}, 'round': {'round_id': 18564, 'name': '1', 'is_current': None}, 'referee_id': 433, 'home_team': {'team_id': 3993, 'name': '1. FC Union Berlin', 'short_code': 'UNI', 'common_name': '', 'logo': 'https://cdn.sportdataapi.com/images/soccer/teams/100/2819.png', 'country': {'country_id': 48, 'name': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de', 'continent': 'Europe'}}, 'away_team': {'team_id': 4075, 'name': 'FC Augsburg', 'short_code': 'FCA', 'common_name': '', 'logo': 'https://cdn.sportdataapi.com/images/soccer/teams/100/2814.png', 'country': {'country_id': 48, 'name': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de', 'continent': 'Europe'}}, 'stats': {'home_score': 1, 'away_score': 3, 'ht_score': '0-1', 'ft_score': '1-3', 'et_score': None, 'ps_score': None}, 'venue': {'venue_id': 1870, 'name': 'An der alten Forsterei', 'capacity': 22012, 'city': 'Berlin', 'country_id': 48}}, {'match_id': 139451, 'status_code': 3, 'status': 'finished', 'match_start': '2020-09-19 13:30:00', 'match_start_iso': '2020-09-19T13:30:00+00:00', 'minute': None, 'league_id': 314, 'season_id': 496, 'stage': {'stage_id': 1, 'name': 'Regular Season'}, 'group': {'group_id': 222, 'group_name': 'Bundesliga'}, 'round': {'round_id': 18564, 'name': '1', 'is_current': None}, 'referee_id': 466, 'home_team': {'team_id': 4070, 'name': 'Werder Bremen', 'short_code': 'SVW', 'common_name': '', 'logo': 'https://cdn.sportdataapi.com/images/soccer/teams/100/2810.png', 'country': {'country_id': 48, 'name': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de', 'continent': 'Europe'}}, 'away_team': {'team_id': 4067, 'name': 'Hertha BSC', 'short_code': 'BSC', 'common_name': '', 'logo': 'https://cdn.sportdataapi.com/images/soccer/teams/100/2806.png', 'country': {'country_id': 48, 'name': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de', 'continent': 'Europe'}}, 'stats': {'home_score': 1, 'away_score': 4, 'ht_score': '0-2', 'ft_score': '1-4', 'et_score': None, 'ps_score': None}, 'venue': {'venue_id': 1930, 'name': 'Weserstadion', 'capacity': 42100, 'city': 'Bremen', 'country_id': 48}}, {'match_id': 139479, 'status_code': 3, 'status': 'finished', 'match_start': '2020-09-19 13:30:00', 'match_start_iso': '2020-09-19T13:30:00+00:00', 'minute': None, 'league_id': 314, 'season_id': 496, 'stage': {'stage_id': 1, 'name': 'Regular Season'}, 'group': {'group_id': 222, 'group_name': 'Bundesliga'}, 'round': {'round_id': 18564, 'name': '1', 'is_current': None}, 'referee_id': 39, 'home_team': {'team_id': 3991, 'name': '1. FC Cologne', 'short_code': 'KOE', 'common_name': '', 'logo': 'https://cdn.sportdataapi.com/images/soccer/teams/100/2809.png', 'country': {'country_id': 48, 'name': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de', 'continent': 'Europe'}}, 'away_team': {'team_id': 4079, 'name': 'TSG 1899 Hoffenheim', 'short_code': 'TSG', 'common_name': '', 'logo': 'https://cdn.sportdataapi.com/images/soccer/teams/100/2818.png', 'country': {'country_id': 48, 'name': 'Germany', 'country_code': 'de', 'continent': 'Europe'}},
```

Now if I do:

```
print(data['data'])
```

It also show me all of the data except query and insider data of query.

Comment: You just have to iterate over the data, and drill down to the `home_team` and `away_team` keys and grab their values.

Comment: I already know what you are saying but i do not how to do this.

Comment: Please make sure your example data is both manageable (not thousands of characters long) and correct (it currently is open-ended). That makes it easier for people to try your data, and provide an answer (possibly with an example).

Comment: Just start at the beginning, and try, bit by bit.

Comment: Sir the data is too long . I can not post all the data here. This is for just how to make the loop for this and grab home and away team from it

Comment: I didn't say to post all the data: you should post a representative example instead. No-one wants to grab all your data and create an example with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` key in your response JSON is a list of dict, you can iterate over the list using a for loop and access `away_team` and `home_team` dictionaries.

```
for d in data['data']:
    print(d['home_team'])
    
for d in data['data']:
    print(d['away_team'])
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers